# Add ElasticSearch Synonyms with Django Haystack

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using Haystack together with Django and I have a search functionality where users search for addresses. 99% of the time the only thing that is localized or changed in the address is the country name. For example, it could say "Germany" or "Deutchland".

I would like to add synonyms to all the countries that I got. So for example Germany would be:

Germany, Deutchland, Tyskland

How do I do this with Haystack?

The engine I'm using is ElasticSearch.

Comment: Can you please show your search index files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to first understand is how this works in ElasticSearch, and then how to bend Haystack to your will. My way of doing this is to provide your own settings dictionary to override the one used by Haystack, specifying the ElasticSearch configuration you want to use.

First you need to set up a [synonyms filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-synonyms.html), which can be done using a synonym configuration file or a list (I heard back from someone else that the list [worked better for them](http://wellfireinteractive.com/blog/custom-haystack-elasticsearch-backend/#comment-917345965)). When ElasticSearch indexes content it first tokenizes it (breaks it up into words or word components) and then filters these components. Filtering is where much of the 'magic' happens, like removing common words, lowercasing, generating synonyms. In order to create synonyms you need to tell ElasticSearch that you want to use a synonym filter, and then you need to provide it with a synonym mapping.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [ 
            "germany,deutchland,tyskland",
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter" 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This configuration tells ElasticSearch to use the [standard tokenizer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html), and then apply the `lowercase` and `my_synonym_filters` in sequence.

The only problem is that there's no way to get these settings applied to your Haystack managed index, at least not out of the box. Haystack's ElasticSearch backend applies its own settings and they can't be directly overrided. However you can, quite easily, create or use a Haystack search backend that extends the base ElasticSearch backend to then use your own search settings. If you're looking for an example of how to do this I would recommend starting with [elasticstack](https://github.com/bennylope/elasticstack/). It's a small toolset designed to attack this problem, mainly providing configurable ElasticSearch settings so you can put analysis settings right in your `settings.py` file.

Answer (score -1):

I should be easily done in your search index files with the use of a tempalte tag.

Supposing the model you'r indexing is an **Adress** your address_text.txt should look like this :

**address_text.tx**

```
{{ object.anyfield }}
{{ object.city }}
{{ objects.country }}
```

You should create a template tag to add Synonyms to your index files

**my_app/templatetags/search_utils.py** (pseudo code... not tested)

```
from django import template
register = template.library

# country names lowercase for easier match
COUNTRY_NAME_SYNONYMS = [
    ['germany', 'deutchland', 'tyskland'],
    ['france', 'frankreich']
]

@register.filter
def add_country_synonyms(country_name):
    synonyms = " ".join([syn_list for syn_list in COUNTRY_NAME_SYNONYMS if country_name.lower() in syn_list])
    return synonyms
```

Finaly make use of your new tag in your **address_text.txt** (index file)

```
# loading the tag    
{% load search_utils %}    

{{ object.anyfield }}
{{ object.city }}
{{ object.country }}
# getting the synonyms
{{ object.country|add_country_synonyms }}
```

Reindex your data and you should find countrys by its synonyms :)

Comment: If I would add all different languages to the document, doesnt that "delude" the data and make it more difficult for ElasticSearch to match the query and to see what is relevant?

For example, if I would have a long description in 10 different languages, so instead of 500 words it would be 5000 words. Wouldnt the users query be "lower scored" matches when 90% of the content in the document is completely different language than the users query?

Comment: Sure it will "delude" the data and search results. In this case i would go for a separate index for each language, here is [an exemple of using haystack for multilangual seach](http://anthony-tresontani.github.io/Django/2012/09/20/multilingual-search/).